# How to mitigate the "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" in a website?

Tags: php, web, http-status-code-404, wamp, windows-server-2019

I hosted a website in Windows Server 2019 ec2 instance using Wamp virtualhost. After access the website over the internet, When register an user in website it outputs following error.

[image]

But in localhost, It works properly without error.

My signup.php file:

[image]

Comment: Does it work with the same URL from LocalHost the way you are trying from remote?

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have already uploaded the image of error and signup.php file

Comment: @BrokenArrow  No it does not also work with the url that contains domain name (www.backpackerctf.online) from local host. But it works fine in (localhost/backpacker) url from local host

Comment: Please read my previous comment again. It says why you should **_not_** upload images of code/errors. Both code and errors are text so you need to copy/paste the actual code/error as text into the question and **_not_** as images.

Comment: It is always a better idea to test your IIS configuration against your domain & DNS with a simple HTML index file before deploying the application. That should clarify where the problem lies in the first place.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Ok. I got the point

Comment: @BrokenArrow I solved the error. It was an error in a hyperlink.